# Swap paragraph content for image using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a client who's needing a quick update, they use woocommerce and are adding a rating attribute to their products,

currently its set up so you can choose a rating (1-5), and it currently outputs that as paragraph text ie `<p>1</p>`

would it be possible with jquery, so that it replaces the text content with an image, dependant on the content, so for example if the content is "1" it replaces it with an image of 1 star, but if the content is "2" it loads an image with 2 stars etc?

Am trying to update this without making too many changes to the core woocommerce php, although i have updated it so that the table row which the paragraph resides within has a class, so:

```
<tr class="rating">
<th>rating</th>
<td><p>1</p></td>
</tr>
```

what i would presume is that I use jquery to change the css styling on the paragraph, so that it uses the relevant star image as the paragraph background, displays block, and indents the text so it cant be seen, but is it possible to have these styles (in particualr the background) dependant on the actual text content in the paragraph?

much thanks in advance!

Comment: There are lots of [JQuery star rating plugins](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=jquery+rating) already written. I suggest using one of those.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('tr.rating').each(function(){
   $(this).find('p').html('<img src="yourimagesfolder/'+($(this).find('p').text()+'.jpg'" />');
   //make sure to have 1.jpg,2.jpg..etc in your images folder   

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes definitely you can have the background for the paragraphs. But you can use some other elements such as div and set some height and width for that div. Based on the content in that div you can fetch the background image and hide the content.

Answer (score 0):

```
$($('#yourTableId tr.rating').each(
    function(){
        var $t = $(this), $p = $t.find('td > p');
        if($p.length){
            $p.addClass($p.text() + 'bg'); // 1bg.jpg ...
            // make sure to create associated classes
        }
    }
));
```